# required field in html form works in chrome but not mobile or ie (done in wordpress)

Tags: html, forms, wordpress, field, required

I am building a form using html in wordpress. The fields that need to be required work in chrome (giving a please fill out this field when the submit button is pressed without information in the field) however it will not work in IE or mobile, it just allows the form to be submitted. Here is a sample of a field

Last name: *

```
input type="text" name="lastname" value="" maxlength="50" required="required"
```

I dont know whats going on here and Im pretty new so any help would be appreciated

(edit with answer)
This is what I ended up doing and it works now thanks for the responses

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["firstname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm" form action="dlcplateFormTest.php"  onsubmit="return validateForm()"                   method="POST">
<tr>
<td>Last name: *</td>
<td><input type="text" name="lastname" value="" maxlength="50" required="required"  />            </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /><input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `required` isn't supported in IE.

Comment: How can I make it work? thanks for the reply

Comment: You need to use JavaScript to validate the form along with serverside validation in the end.

Comment: ok Ill look into how to do that thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

you need to write a javascript function that checks if the fields are "" or not if they are "" then cancel request